# InsertSubviewBelow not working properly; view displays ABOVE other view

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Got a question for you guys. In my program, I have a `UIPageViewController` that is added as a child view controller via `this.NavigationController.AddChildViewController(pvController)` and is added as a subview of my current View via `View.AddSubview(pvController.View)`

I have added a transition to my View such that it slides down on the Y axis by 250 units:

```
UIView.Transition(this.View, 1.5, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, () =>
            {
                this.View.Frame = animateTo;
            }, null);
```

I want another `UIView` to be behind the `UIPageViewController.View` such that when I trigger my transition, the other view seems to slide into place. The problem is, I've tried so many various ways to do this to no avail. Here are all of the ways that I've tried to do this thus far:

```
        View.SendSubviewToBack(behind);
        pvController.View.InsertSubviewBelow(behind, pvController.View);
        pvController.View.InsertSubviewAbove(behind, pvController.View);
        pvController.View.SendSubviewToBack(behind);
```

They all result in the same thing: the UIView `behind` is displayed *above* the `pvController.View`

Anyone have any ideas? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it! It was slightly simpler than I thought; though, I do still wonder why InsertSubviewBelow did not work.

Here is what I did to achieve my desired effects:

```
View.AddSubview(pvController.View);
View.AddSubview(behind);
View.SendSubviewToBack(behind);
```

And when the view loaded, after `ViewDidLoad()`, `behind` was indeed behind `pvController.View`!

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to your problem, but something you can use to help troubleshoot it.

In XCode, it is possible to [debug your view hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html), which may help you see where your views are.

To access this feature, click on this window while your app is at a breakpoint:

[image]

That will then show the following in XCode:

[image]

Hopefully, this can help you figure out just where the view is.

Comment: I appreciate it brotha, definitely some extra knowledge that I didn't have before. But, I just figured out how to do what I was looking for, as you can see below. Thanks man!